# discord.py: I want to grab a specific set of numbers from a message, but i'm stuck

Tags: python, discord.py

I am making a bot that links users to the [SCP Wiki (The foundation one)](http://scp-wiki.net). I want my bot to be able to pick up a SCP classification (i.e. SCP-370) and return a message with the link to the scp wiki, with that number (i.e. http://scp-wiki.net/scp-370)

I've tried a few things, such as:

```py
def scp_url(num):
    return "http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-" + num

def scp_link(num):
    return "[SCP-" + num + "](" + scp_url(num) + ")"

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "SCP" in message.content:    
        msg = scp_link
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
```

Or:

```py
if int in message.content:
    int = num
```

I just can't find a way to grab the numbers from the message.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: it sounds like we need to write one function with clearly defined inputs and outputs. Can you define those inputs and outputs, maybe define a few examples in a table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, you need to know the format of the input. 
From your question I see it's not command because it will check every message for SCP string. But will the string be formatted as `SCP-1` or `SCP-001` or `SCP 1`?

You need to take care of all of those cases or just make 1 selected case and deal with that. Here's my fully commented code which deals with all 3 cases:

```
# Number separator is character between SCP and a number, example with space:
# SCP 1
NUMBER_SEPARATOR = " "
MAXIMUM_SCP_NUMBER = 4999


def get_scp_link(message_content):
    word_list = message_content.split(NUMBER_SEPARATOR)
    scp_number = _extract_scp_number(word_list)
    if scp_number is not None:
        try:
            # int(scp_number) takes care if users already entered 001
            # because it makes it equal to 1
            formatted_number = _format_scp_number(int(scp_number))
            return _build_scp_url(formatted_number)
        except Exception:
            return None


# @param word_list a list of strings
# @return integer or None if error
def _extract_scp_number(word_list):
    captured_scp_number = None

    for index, word in enumerate(word_list):
        if word == "SCP":
            # We're gonna return the word after the current word (index+1)
            # But we have to make sure that the next word exists in the list
            # otherwise we will get IndexError exception
            if index + 1 < len(word_list):
                captured_scp_number = word_list[index + 1]
            else:
                return None
    # If we captured a string in the for loop we have to make sure that that
    # string is actually a number and not some random word example "SCP blabla"
    if captured_scp_number is not None and captured_scp_number.isdigit():
        return captured_scp_number
    return None


# Formats number as a string in format 001-MAXIMUM_SCP_NUMBER
# This allows users to enter 1 instead of 001.
#
# @param number a positive integer to be formatted
# @return string in format 001-MAXIMUM_SCP_NUMBER or raise Exception if error
def _format_scp_number(number):
    if number == 0:
        raise Exception("SCP 0 doesn't exist!")
    elif number > MAXIMUM_SCP_NUMBER:
        raise Exception("SCP number too high! Entry doesn't exist!")
    elif number < 10:
        return "00" + str(number)
    elif number < 100:
        return "0" + str(number)
    else:
        return str(number)


# @param formatted_scp_number a string in format 001-MAXIMUM_SCP_NUMBER
# @return string representing URL to SCP-number web page
def _build_scp_url(formatted_scp_number):
    base_url = "http://www.scp-wiki.net/scp-"
    prefix = "[SCP-" + formatted_scp_number + "]"
    return prefix + base_url + formatted_scp_number

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if "SCP" in message.content:
        scp_link = get_scp_link(message.content)
        if scp_link is not None:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, scp_link)
```

Comment below for any questions or suggestions.

Comment: If they are all functions, where do i put them in the code? Also, for the last function, at the very last line, i get an error saying 'await is outside async function. Aside from that, thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Ah sorry I removed that when I tested locally and forgot to put it back. I've edited it should work now. As those are functions you can put them anywhere, you can just copy paste the code as it is and paste it to your script where you already have the `on_message` function

Comment: This is great. I do get an 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'isdigit'' error whenever i use it, but it still works, so i don't mind it. Once again, thank for your time and effort into making this code!